# Large-scale rotational invariance in lattice space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, computational-physics, discrete, lattice-model

It is often claimed among physicists that rotational invariance can emerge at large scales in lattice space. Let's focus on quantum mechanics for now. I interpret this claim as follows (I am a philosopher, so I will be relatively wordy and not technically sophisticated but I focus on conceptual clarity):

*Claim*. Suppose space is discrete and every point can be represented by members of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. For any quantum mechanical system $\alpha$ with initial position $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, for any $y,z\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ that have approximately the same Euclidean distance to $x$, the amplitudes of $\alpha$ at $y$ and $z$ are approximately the same when the Euclidean distance in question is sufficiently large.

*Question*: is this claim true? If it is true, what is the proof? If it is false, is there a true claim in its vicinity?
I calculate the wavefunction in this lattice space, and cannot infer this claim. In addition, I did some numerical evaluations at Wolframalpha and the result suggests that the *Claim* is false. Here're my main steps:

0. Assume that $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Psi (t,x) =\Psi(t, x+e_i)-\Psi(t,x)  \textrm{ or}  =\Psi(t,x)-\Psi(t, x-e_i)$$
1. Start from the Schrodinger equation in lattice space. The discrete Hamiltonian is $$\hat{H}\Psi(t,x)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i(\Psi(t, x+e_i)+\Psi(t,x-e_i)-2\Psi(t,x)).$$
   Here, $\Psi$ is the position space wavefunction: $\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{C}.$
2. Its fourier series in the momentum space is:
   $$\tilde{\Psi}(t,p)= \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-2\pi i p x} \Psi (t,x) $$ with $\tilde{\Psi}(t): \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{C}$.
3. Since $\tilde{\Psi}(t)$ is periodical, we can just represent its domain by $B=[-1/2,1/2]\times [-1/2,1/2]$. The momentum space Hamiltonian is:
   $$\tilde{H}\Psi(t,p)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i(e^{2\pi i p_i}+e^{-2\pi i p_i}-2)\tilde{\Psi}(t,p)$$
   with $p_i=p\cdot e_i$.
4. Solve the Schrodinger equation in the momentum space, we have
   $$\tilde{\Psi} (t,p)=(e^{-i\tilde{H}t}\tilde{\Psi})(p)=e^{-i\mathbf{Cow}(p)t}\tilde{\Psi}(0,p)$$
   where $\mathbf{Cow}(p)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i(e^{2\pi i p_i}+e^{-2\pi i p_i}-2)$. Transform it back to the position space:
   $$\Psi (t,x)=\int_{p\in B} e^{2\pi i px}e^{-i\mathbf{Cow}(p)t}\tilde{\Psi}(0,p)dp=\int_{p\in B} e^{2\pi i px}e^{-i\mathbf{Cow}(p)t}dp$$

(the above integral seems to be equal to $e^{-nit}\prod_nI_{x_n}(it)$ where $I$ is modified Bessel function.)

5. $$\mathbf{Cow}(p) = -\sum_i(cos(2\pi p_i)-1) =  -\sum_i(1-2\pi^2p_i^2-1+O(p_i^4))=2\pi^2\sum_ip_i^2 - O(p^4)$$

From this, it seems that $\Psi (t,x)$ is not rotational variant because  $O(p^4)$ cannot be ignored in the integral. In any case, I do not see how to show the *Claim* to be true.

I will edit further if there is inclarity. Thanks advance for helps! Partial answers are also welcome!

Comment: Step 4 looks like a *specific* solution of the Schrödinger equation. Do you have a reason for focusing on this specific solution? The claim applies only in the low-momentum approximation, so you need to restrict the solution-set to solutions that only involve low momenta $|p|\ll 1$.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I edited the step 4 to make its steps clearer. When you say restrict solutions to low momenta, do you mean I should modify *Claim* in a certain way in order for it to be true?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to see that this claim is true is to look at the dispersion diagrams for periodic structures. Since such diagrams represent the Fourier domain, large scales are represented by the region near the original. There the dispersion curve is often rotationally symmetric.